# How does the chance of an event change for different sample sizes?

Tags: probability

Let's assume we have played a game 4000 times and found that there was a 10 % chance of losing more than *X* times in a row.

**My question:**
How would I calculate the chance for the same losing streak over the course of only 500 iterations of the game?
My guess is that the chance of an occurrence is directly proportional to the sample size, so I would simply do this: 
`10 % / 8 = 1.25 %`

Is it really that simple or am I completely off?

Comment: With the same reasoning the chance of a losing streak over $80000$ iterations would be $10\% \cdot 20=200\%$.

Comment: @ErikThörnblad You're so right, can't believe that I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the chances that an event occurs in $n$ iterations are $p$, then, assuming that the proper independence properties hold, one sees that the chances it does not occur in $n$ iterations are $1-p$, hence the chances it does not occur in $kn$ iterations are $(1-p)^k$ hence the chances it occurs in $kn$ iterations are $1-(1-p)^k$.

To sum up, when one multiplies the number of iterations by $k$, instead of replacing the chances $p$ that an event occurs by $kp$ (as you suggest), one should replace $p$ by $1-(1-p)^k$.

Conversely, if the chances that an event occurs in $kn$ iterations are $p$, the chances that it occurs in $n$ iterations are $1-(1-p)^{1/k}$. For example, $10\%$ chances of some losing streak in $4000$ iterations yields $1.308\%$ chances of the same losing streak in $500$ iterations.

Comment: What happens if the independence properties don't hold?

Comment: Basically anything can.